Tense usage in counterfactual conditionals with non-counterfactual clauses
Imagine the following situation:
My superior is to come with an inspection is a few hours. The visit is expected to be quite unpleasant and therefore I write to my absent coworker to urge him to come:

If you were here, it wouldn't be that much of an embarrassment.

This is a conditional speculating about some hypothetical situation, and albeit pertinent to the present, it uses the "fake past" construction to convey counterfactuality. Clear and sound.
But if we modify the statement:

If you were here when the boss comes/came, it wouldn't be that much of an embarrassment.

Now it speculates about some hypothetical situation in the future.
And here is the question: which tense is appropriate for the clause specifying some non-counterfactual future reference point, concretely, "comes" or "came"?

Fake past or real, we “backshift” for best results; came is correct.

While this may be proper, it can be confusing, because it shifts from apparent present to the future. Rewriting to "If you could be here when the boss comes, it won't be that much of an embarassment." solves this.

Or more simply "If you come in, ..."
